# What are the situations that make sense to hire a labor lawyer to keep your job?

Tags: performance-reviews, law

I have a situation at work and am trying to figure out when it's appropriate to hire a labor lawyer to fight for my job.

**Some background:**
I was performing to expectations and have exceeded expectations in many categories in my reviews.

Then...
I voiced my concern that upper management was not taking my views on industry trends seriously and have actually belittled my suggestions. I even mentioned in subsequent years that we're missed out on trends that I  called out.

After that I have been called out on lots of little things that are not very SMART (specific, measurable, achievable, relevant, time bound). I.e. they are not data based.

Eventually they issued a PIP but I worked through that, according to my immediate manager, in the best way possible. I feel like upper management basically wants to fire me because they are covering the fact that they ignored me on business opportunities.

Is this a situation to consult a labor lawyer?

(I may not even want to stay at the job because of the negativity with upper management)

Comment: "Way more critical than they were before" doesn't mean "illegal". If you managed to get through a PIP, you worked crazy hard, they're not trying to get rid of you (any more?) or they're being extremely careful to not do anything which might give you a decent legal case. Why would you *want* to keep your job if you're having issues with management? Are you having trouble finding another one?

Comment: A lawyer would ask you the same question that I am asking you now: *To what end?* It is not like you can court-order management to like you so unless they do something out of line, what do you want to sue for?

Comment: To answer the more general question (speculatively), I imagine something like a cash settlement would be the end goal in most cases instead of getting the job back.

Comment: Where are you located? Employment laws vary a lot depending on where you are.

Comment: I think the bridges are already burned.  Move on as fast as you can.

Comment: the update question is highly opinion based, now. Only OP can determine if it is best to do so, but as indicated in my answer, seems that perhaps you should indeed be looking to leave ASAP

Comment: I still don't see wah legal case you want to argue here? Are there any (monetary) damages that you can prove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the situations that make sense to hire a labor lawyer to keep your job?

It always makes sense ... for the labor lawyer. It *never* makes sense for *you* to hire a labor lawyer *to keep your job*. If you have been accused of fraud or some other major offense, it makes sense to hire a labor lawyer *to clear your name* (and not *to keep your job*.)

In all other cases, [you always lose by hiring a labor lawyer](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MortonsFork). Even if you win and get to keep your job, you will still get treated as a social outcast, which means you will probably end up leaving the job soon anyway. (And no, you cannot sue them *again* to force them to treat you normally.)

Regardless of the outcome of the case, you lose a lot of your effort and "life energy" fighting the case, not to mention lawyer fees and court fees. (Some courts may order the company to reimburse you those fees if you win, but that also means you may have to pay *their* fees if you lose.)

Moreover, you are up against an entity which likely keeps multiple lawyers on their payroll, so the odds are usually stacked against you. That doesn't mean you can never win, of course. However, unless you feel that strongly about the issue, my advice would be to let it go and spend your efforts, "life energy" and money looking for a better job.

Remember life is short, don't waste it fighting unnecessary battles. One who runs away from a fight lives to run another day. :-)

Comment: Not sure about the never. I could see it when there is a mass firing (get rid of half of a division) and the selection may be unfair or something - but that REALLY depends on jurisdictions and is a VERY rare edge case. Still it is not "never."

Answer (score 6):

> Is this a situation to consult a labor lawyer?
>
> (I may not even want to stay at the job bc of the negativity with upper management)

If you don't want to stat in that job then I don't see the point of hiring a lawyer to "fight for your job".

Seems that perhaps what you want and should be doing is updating your resume, and start looking for jobs ASAP, in some other place more fit to your expectations.

However, I must also say that **don't expect upper management to implement every (or any) suggestion you make**. It is *their* job to make managerial decisions, and if you made your suggestion and opinion as per *your* job and role in the company then there is few other things you can do.

Hopefully you have documented or evidenced such suggestions (email, or similar), so if this eventually falls down it won't come down at you. But still, if you feel in such way perhaps the best thing you can do is to look for other job.

Answer (score 3):

Very rare. It *may* make sense if there is one person who wants you out, and your lawyer can convince your company that the other person is a liability and not you. Very rare. If the company itself wants you out, not a chance.

What makes a lot more sense is at times to hire a lawyer to get the best financial compensation for having to leave your job. A good lawyer will listen to what you have to say and give you good advice whether to proceed with the case or not.